# Pagination with Google Maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps, pagination

I am trying use Google Maps for my work; I have downloaded an example and trying to modify it, but I am not so good in jQuery. Please look at these two links:

http://drmorphe.us/tests/googleMaps/jquery-google-maps-extend-with-pagination.html

That link is working fine and changing locations, but this style is not good if we have many records. I have around 500 records, I am planning to bind these in 'datatables' but I don't know how can I make links which works fine.

Look at what I am trying to achieve:

http://drmorphe.us/tests/googleMaps/jquery-google-maps-extend-with-pagination2.html

This way I can show links but I need them to work and these should take us on exact Longitude and Latitude provided (panTo).

P.S. jquery.ui.map.extentions.js has been modified to achieve this goal.

Comment: Just a quick tip - links are fine in questions, but it is generally a good idea to make questions 'self-contained', so that readers don't have to click on several links to understand what you need. That said, from what I can tell you just want to have a list of links on the left hand side, each of which is clickable and re-centres the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application does not function properly because of JavaScript errors.

Please open `jquery.ui.map.extension2.js` file and edit line `119`. The `onclick` event should not start with `"function("`. Instead of

```
onclick="function(map.panTo(new GLatLng(33.69877782,73.00711869)));"
```

write

```
onclick="map.panTo(new GLatLng(33.69877782,73.00711869));"
```

Comment: Thanks Alexios and everyone for reply, unfortunately this is still not working for me.

I am not good in programming, I am a designer but I have to do it for my company.

Comment: @Dr.Morpheus - just so you know, other people who've responded won't get a 'new message notification' when you reply here - only Alexios does. Reply to people directly under their answer, or under the question using the 'at' prefix with their username to address them.

Comment: (That said, the advice here seems pretty sound. Look at line 119 and try the edit @Alexious suggests).

Comment: I am confused, I have copy pasted your code in line 119, only changed values of Latitude and Longitude, I have also changed double quote to a single quote otherwise my Dreamweaver was giving me an error. Also links on the website is updated to verify.

I have uploaded files here 
http://drmorphe.us/tests/googleMaps/jQuery_Map.rar

I seriously need help and this solution seems to me very good as I don't know JSON and other languages but I don't know where I am mistaking.

Please help

@Alexious halfer

Comment: I am wondering if this 'map' is correct ot we are not reaching the original map?

Comment: @Dr.Morpheus: that didn't notify me. Under Alexious' answer, he is notified automatically. To notify me under someone else's answer, use (at)halfer (using the symbol, obviously). You can only notify one person at a time.

Comment: Are you looking at the errors in your browser's JavaScript console? It seems that the second link in your question now has an undeclared variable ('map') when a location is clicked on. (People are unlikely to download your rar file - put it on a web server if there's something else people need to see).

Comment: I have fixed all errors and checked google documentation but no luck, this is a good example of what I want to do, http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/sidebar/random-markers.html
@halfer

Comment: @Dr.Morpheus: if you publish your work - perhaps to a third link? - then someone may advise. But if I can't see your progress, I cannot advise you.

Comment: @halfer I am sorry to bug you, at this point my question is very simple how can I reach to map object to panTo. this `map.panTo.LatLng(33.69877782,73.00711869)` is not correct if anyone can tell me what is the exact syntax.

Comment: @Dr.Morpheus: I think you'll need to work that out - the issue is that there is no such variable as 'map' (you were right before: you are not reaching the original map). You'll need to retrieve the map object created by your code, and then access the Google API inside it (the syntax for which may well be `panTo.LatLng`). More info [here](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/gmap-plugin-modifying-a-json-object) but I think you will need a programmer for this one!

Comment: @halfer : I fixed that issue, only a small problem left, look at the map now, http://drmorphe.us/tests/finalMap/map.html its taking me to that place but zooming to maximum level, I have tried some combinations but that didn't work, any hint?

Comment: I think it's the `zoom: 10` on line 24 in that source. Make that something like 4 or 5?

Comment: Zoom at loading of page is 10 which is fine, but upon clicking zoom will be 21, I want to restrict it to 10 only.

Comment: @Dr.Morpheus: The problem is not zooming out at all. Yuo got some major issues. The plotter function is at best unstable. Here is what is happening:

When you get max_lat & max_lng, the values are the same basically.

Then you create a bounded rectangle with actually the same points on earth. This triggers the map to zoom automatically to the maximum zoom level.

Apart from the above, the function is called correctly at startup and every time you click on a label. The function then creates a new map, which should be avoided for memory sake.

Please tell me if you need any further assistance.

Comment: @AlexiosTsiaparas: that was a great help actually, This map will be used rarely so only fixing the zoom will be fine at the point, I have changed max_lat and max_lng to 70 and -70 and its working fine for me, in future when we need it properly I will have enough time and we will hire a programmer to do that. Great thanks for this help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few tips, assuming you want to look up these locations from a live database.

1. Render a list of links, with a unique `id` on each one
2. Get a click event working on each one, returning false so the event doesn't bubble up.
3. Attach the one click handler to every item, maybe through a class on each item.
4. In the handler, detect the `id`, and send it to the server via AJAX.
5. In the server, look up the coordinates, and render them in JSON.
6. Grab the coordinates in JavaScript and re-centre the map, or create a new pin, etc.

That should get you sorted!